# Sql Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS) em Computador local foi iniciado é interrompido?

Tags: sql-server

Olá, 
Tenho uma máquina com o windows 10

Fiz a instalação do SQL Server normalmente, estava funcionando, só que agora o SQL Server não inicia, fui ao gerenciador de serviços é ao tentar inicializar tenho a mensagem:

O serviço Sql Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS) em Computador local foi iniciado é interrompido. Alguns serviços são interrompidos automaticamente se não estiverem sendo usados por outros serviços e programas

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema :s

Comment: Ooo amigo...faz o seguinte..eu nao manjo nao mas toda vez q da essa pau ae eu habilito todos os protocolos la no SQL Server Configuration Manager e abro o Serviços em modo administrador. Ae em Serviços eu inicio o Agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boas,

O **SQL Server Agent (SQLExpress)** não é o serviço principal do *SQL Server*.
Você deve arrancar o serviço **SQL Server (SQLExpress)** que é bem diferente do *Agent*.

O *SQL Server Agent* é responsável pelas tarefas pro-activas do SQL Server. Ou seja, toda operação programada do SQL Server para correr num determinado período (ex: Backups) é gerenciada pelo Agent. O *Agent* jamais irá arrancar se o **SQL Server** normal não estiver iniciado.
O que quer dizer que não é esse serviço que você deve arrancar, mas sim o que lhe indiquei. Caso não tenha sucesso, recomendo-o a verificar o Event Viewer do sistema operativo.

**Possíveis causas:**

- O seu windows pode estar sobre-carregago no seu arranque;
- O seu SQL Server pode ter uma Base de Dados muito pesada o que combinado com o arranque do windows, pode resultar numa outra sobre-carga;

Answer (score -1):

Esse problema ocorre em versões de Windows que não sejam em inglês.

No diretório no qual se encontra o serviço, abra o arquivo "SQLScheduler.WindowsService.exe.config". Nele, procure o atributo "'authorizedGroup" e altere de "everyone" para "todos". Inicie o serviço normalmente.

Espero ter ajudado!

Fábio Rocha

Answer (score -2):

O SQL Server Agent não funciona nas edições Express do SQL Server. Embora o serviço conste como instalado, ele jamais pode ser ativado. Isso consta na documentação [Recursos com suporte nas edições do SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc645993.aspx).